# Avoid duplicated function code in NSIS

Tags: nsis

Currently, I have the following scripts code.

```
Section "Uninstall"
...
...
Call un.DeleteDirIfEmpty 
SectionEnd


Function GetJRE
    ; Call must not be used with functions starting with "un." in the non-uninstall sections.
    Call
FunctionEnd


Function un.DeleteDirIfEmpty
...
...
FunctionEnd

Function DeleteDirIfEmpty
...
...
FunctionEnd
```

Note that, I need to provide 2 versions of DeleteDirIfEmpty, so that the same operation can be performed in non-uninstall section and uninstall section.

Their code is the same, just that the naming is different. `un.DeleteDirIfEmpty` and `DeleteDirIfEmpty`

How is it possible to have only 1 function, but is callable by any section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at \Include\Util.nsh, it is used to turn a macro into a function:

```
!include Util.nsh

!macro MyFunction
MessageBox mb_ok "Hello World"
!macroend
!define MyFunction "${CallArtificialFunction} MyFunction"

Section
${MyFunction}
SectionEnd
```

Note: To delete a empty directory, just use `RMDir` (Without /r switch)

Comment: "To delete a empty directory, just use RMDir (Without /r switch)" is a nice hint too. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Anders, could you edit your answer with an example on how to call the shared function? When I call `${MyFunction}` from a section, I get error "not valid function command to call from section" or something similar. Likewise I am not sure what is the role of `${CallArtificialFunction}` in your code.

Comment: I am interested in it because your solution looks cleaner than the solution I provided from this [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Sharing_functions_between_Installer_and_Uninstaller). Which method do you recommend? I prefer readability in less verbosity than power or flexibility. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Sharing_functions_between_Installer_and_Uninstaller) helped me understand as well. It provides an example showing how to share functionality between installer and uninstaller. Say, you have a function which should be shared called `myfunc`, then you create a macro to call it from the uninstaller too. Quoting from the link:

```
; Name of our installer.
Name "Function Sharing Example"
OutFile "FunctionShareExample.exe"
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\Function Sharing Example\"

; We need some pages.
Page directory
Page instfiles
; And uninstaller pages.
UninstPage uninstconfirm
UninstPage instfiles

; Show the details.
ShowInstDetails show
ShowUninstDetails show

; ******************* The shared function. *******************
!macro MYMACRO un
  Function ${un}myfunc
    MessageBox MB_OK "This is the function ${un}myfunc."
    DetailPrint "Very ${un}funny text."
    DetailPrint "More ${un}funny text."
  FunctionEnd
!macroend

; Insert function as an installer and uninstaller function.
!insertmacro MYMACRO ""
!insertmacro MYMACRO "un."

Section "Install"
  ; ******************* Call the installer function. *******************
  Call myfunc

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  ; Write an uninstaller.
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
  ShowWindow $HWNDPARENT 6
  ; Show the install directory, so you can run the uninstaller straight away.
  ExecShell open "$INSTDIR"
  Sleep 1000
  ShowWindow $HWNDPARENT 9
SectionEnd

Section "Uninstall"
  ; ******************* Call the un.installer function. *******************
  Call un.myfunc

  ; Clean up install directory (delete it).
  Delete "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @rakhi4110 well I will include the essentials, but I felt I would be not doing justice to original author for merely copying.

Comment: You would still be providing the link and crediting the original author for it. Just that you are providing the excerpt here, so as to make sure, the answer is available to everyone, even if the link is down / expires / migrated.